# Store logs from Netgear N150 WGR614

Tags: ssh, telnet, router, tftp

Trying to fetch logs about client activity from Netgear N150 WGR614 but even after enabling telnet using this [script](https://code.google.com/p/netgear-telnetenable/) i was not able to do that. Anybody know which variant supports SSH/TFTP/Telnet so that i can access it like linux machine (some have busybox) and store logs.